# How to get both array key from value in 2 dimensional array (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$arr['animal'][0] = 'Dog';
$arr['animal'][1] = 'Cat';
```

From that array basically I need to create a function with the array value parameter and then it gives me the array keys.

For example:

```
find_index('Cat');
```

Output :

The result is animal, 1

Comment: It's a possibility that your data structure is simply wrong if this is the primary purpose of your code ... could you explain why it needs to be done this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do something like

```
function find_index($value) {
  foreach ($arr as $index => $index2) {
    $exists = array_search($value, $index2);
    if ($exists !== false) {
      echo "The result is {$index}, {$exists}";
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: So what is linked with OP Question??

Comment: Mindastic: why break rather than return? Abdulla: huh this is exactly what OP asked...

Comment: LOL! i don't know, i just started writing the function and didn't think about the return option but, agreed, return would be better. Changing it now.

Comment: (1) this currently has a variable scope issue, unless the array `$arr` is added inside the function or as a function parameter. (2) `$index2` is an array, so `echo "The result is {$index}, {$index2}";` will return a `Array to string conversion` notice, and a response of `The result is animal, Array`. easily solved by changing `foreach ($index2 as $val)` to `foreach ($index2 as $key => $val)`, and `echo "The result is {$index}, {$index2}";` to `echo "The result is {$index}, {$key}";`

Comment: hmmm I get  this output instead :

The result is Animal, Array

Comment: Thanks Sean! I appreciate it Mindastic, edit your answer like Sean said, your answer then will be perfect! :)

Comment: I changed my answer but i did it sightly different to the solution proposed by @Sean (that was good, though). Check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr['animal'][0] = 'Dog';
$arr['animal'][1] = 'Cat';

function find_index($searchVal, $arr){
    return array_search($searchVal, $arr);
}

print_r(find_index('Cat', $arr['animal']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Array,

```
$arr['animal'][] = 'Dog';
$arr['animal'][] = 'Cat';

$arr['insects'][] = 'Insect1';
$arr['insects'][] = 'Insect2';
```

Here is Iterator Method,

```
$search = 'InsectSub1';
$matches = [];

$arr_array = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr);
$arr_array_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($arr_array);

foreach($arr_array_iterator as $key => $value)
{
    if($value === $search)
    {
        $fill = [];
        $fill['category'] = $arr_array->key();
        $fill['key'] = $arr_array_iterator->key();
        $fill['value'] = $value;
        $matches[] = $fill;
    }
}

if($matches)
{
    // One or more Match(es) Found
}
else
{
    // Not Found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr['animal'][] = 'Dog';
$arr['animal'][] = 'Cat';
$arr['insects'][] = 'Insect1';
$arr['insects'][] = 'Insect2';

$search_for = 'Cat';
$search_result = [];

while ($part = each($arr)) {
    $found = array_search($search_for, $part['value']);
    if(is_int($found)) {
        $fill = [ 'key1' => $part['key'], 'key2' => $found ];
        $search_result[] = $fill;
    }
}

echo 'Found '.count($search_result).' result(s)';
print_r($search_result);
```